# MySQL SELECT to VIEW returns different results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

I have put together a small sql query which brings data from one table and sorts it under new column names. The sql looks like this:

```
SELECT course_id AS course, NOW() as datum,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_courses WHERE course_id = course) AS antal_registrerade,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_courses WHERE status = 1 AND course_id = course) AS antal_aktiva,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_courses WHERE status = 3 AND course_id = course) AS antal_avklarade
FROM users_courses GROUP BY course_id
```

The above query returns the following:

```
| course | datum               | antal_registrerade | antal_aktiva  | antal_avklarade   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 31     | 2016-01-12 16:24:58 | 142                | 19            | 83                |
| 38     | 2016-01-12 16:24:58 | 826                | 45            | 49                |
| 39     | 2016-01-12 16:24:58 | 2                  | 2             | NULL              |
| 43     | 2016-01-12 16:24:58 | 169                | 29            | 32                |
| 44     | 2016-01-12 16:24:58 | 11                 | 4             | 2                 |
| 45     | 2016-01-12 16:24:58 | 67                 | 8             | 7                 |
| 46     | 2016-01-12 16:24:58 | 2                  | 1             | 1                 |
```

All good right? Just like I wanted it. BUT when I save this query as a view and run that the result is different. I get the same data for every row, except for the course and datum columns.

```
| course | datum               | antal_registrerade | antal_aktiva  | antal_avklarade   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 31     | 2016-01-12 16:24:58 | 1219               | 108           | 174               |
| 38     | 2016-01-12 16:24:58 | 1219               | 108           | 174               |
| 39     | 2016-01-12 16:24:58 | 1219               | 108           | 174               |
| 43     | 2016-01-12 16:24:58 | 1219               | 108           | 174               |
| 44     | 2016-01-12 16:24:58 | 1219               | 108           | 174               |
| 45     | 2016-01-12 16:24:58 | 1219               | 108           | 174               |
| 46     | 2016-01-12 16:24:58 | 1219               | 108           | 174               |
```

Anyone have any idea why this is? The sql found in the saved view looks like this:

```
SELECT `database`.`users_courses`.`course_id` AS `course`,now() AS `datum`,
(SELECT COUNT(0) from `database`.`users_courses` where (`database`.`users_courses`.`course_id` = `database`.`users_courses`.`course_id`)) AS `antal_registrerade`,
(SELECT COUNT(0) from `database`.`users_courses` where ((`database`.`users_courses`.`status` = 1) and (`database`.`users_courses`.`course_id` = `database`.`users_courses`.`course_id`))) AS `antal_aktiva`,
(SELECT COUNT(0) from `database`.`users_courses` where ((`database`.`users_courses`.`status` = 3) and (`database`.`users_courses`.`course_id` = `database`.`users_courses`.`course_id`))) AS `antal_avklarade`
FROM `database`.`users_courses`
GROUP BY `database`.`users_courses`.`course_id`
```

Comment: what does your view look like? - i mean the code for the view

Comment: @DanielCasserly I've updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much simpler to express using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT course_id AS course, NOW() as datum,
       COUNT(*) as antal_registrerade,
       SUM(status = 1) as antal_aktiva,
       SUM(status = 3) AS antal_avklarade
FROM users_courses
GROUP BY course_id;
```

This should fix the problem with your results.

For some reason, the saved code for the view has the correlation clause incorrect.  My guess is that you don't have two columns in the table for `course` and `course_id`, so your first query isn't exactly what is going into the view.  In any case, fix this using a simpler query.

Comment: Oh wow, that's beautiful. Makes a lot more sense and is a much more elegant solution. Thanks! Problem solved!